# Connecting Derby DB to Oracle SQL Data Modeler

Tags: java, sql, oracle, data-modeling

Can someone help me please?

I have an existing database created via NetBeans on the Java DB server and I recently got myself the Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler, but I'm struggling a bit to connect to my Derby database.

I've read some other questions and topics on this and tried to reproduce the steps, but for some reason, I fail.

I have included the Derby JARs on Oracle, and tried to set up my database connection (Username omitted):
[image: New Connection]

Note the error when trying the connection: Driver class not found.

I have also used *org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver* as Driver Class

Could someone please give me a quick tutorial through this for specifically Derby? I also tried it according to the App's help manual.

Answer (score 0):

I think your driver is not pointed in your CLASSPATH. I dont know how to do it on Netbeans; most of ides has options to include class (and automatically includes on path), if not try to include on CLASSPATH by hand.

Comment: I tried that now, doesn't seem to work... echo %CLASSPATH% > C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\db\lib\derby.jar

Comment: Mmmmm it is not clear for me if netbeans will use system classpath. Most of ides uses it on the fly (adding classpath directly to the java executing comand). Did you figure it out how to add libraries to netbeans?

Comment: Not sure if you maybe missed it, but I'm working with Oracle Developer Data Modeler, not NetBeans. Thanks for the help thusfar!

Comment: Mmm Sorry. By the way classpath should be defined in system properties on Windows i think. Are you trying to run from command line?